# What's the difference between this two PHP object instantiation types?

Tags: php, object

I wonder about the differences of this PHP instantiation type.

`$object = new MyClass();`

vs

`$this->object = new MyClass();`

What's the difference between this two?

Comment: It is not about *instantiation*, it is about *assignment*. How does `$x = y` differ from `$this->x = y`? What is `$x` what is `$this->x`?

Answer (score 1):

The first one instantiates an object of `MyClass` to a variable *object* in `variable-scope`.

The second one instantiates an object of `MyClass` in another(not necessarily a different one) class object attributes value.